# Ubuntu boot error: how to repair encrypted ssd from Ubuntu USB boot?

Tags: boot, live-usb, data-recovery, boot-repair, recovery-mode

When I startup my Dell Xps 13 9350 on which the Ubuntu 18.04 is the only OS installed, after inserting the encryption/decryption password for the ssd, I get the following error.

```
Error: failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to device scanning.
Volume group "ubuntu-vg" not found
Cannot process volume group ubuntu-vg.
Warning: failed to connect to lvmetad.Falling back to device scanning.
Reading all physical volumes. This may take a while...
Found volume ubuntu-vg using metadata type lvm2
Warning: failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to device scanning.
2 logical volume(s) in volume-group "ubuntu-vg" now active
Gave up waiting
touch: /dev/.initramfs/jasper.log: no such file or directory
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg--root: clean 1469151/30154752 files, 119168259/120604672 blocks
```

I flashed Ubuntu on a USB stick and thought I can use `fsck` to repair the encrypted disk.

Since the disk is encrypted I did:

```
cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/nvme0n1p3 someName
```

and entered the password.

Now I tried to run:

```
sudo e2fsck /deve/mapper/someName
```

but I get the error:

```
/dev/mapper/someName is in use:
e2fsck cannot continue, aborting.
```

I tried to `umount` bothe `someName` and the ecnrypted disk partition `/dev/nvme0n1p3` but neither of them is mounted.

How can I repair my disck with `e2fsck` or any other way (without loosing my files)?

Comment: Any idea how it may have gotten corrupted?  If it is an NVMe drive, you may want to just try and re-seat it. Several people had luck just by falling back to an old kernel at boot. You should try that first. Other than that, i did find a post by someone else that was successful at fixing theirs (older version of Ubuntu though). Here is that link: https://askubuntu.com/questions/745218/ubuntu-wont-boot-because-of-lvmetad

Comment: It might have got corrupted by overwriting some filesystem data (I was doing an external hd recovery). Also why doing it the computer was very warm: I don't know if high temperature may corrupt some data.

Comment: Heat shouldn't cause data loss unless we are talking about extreme heat for long periods. That HDD recovery may have caused some issues (cant be sure without more details). Try to hold down shift key at boot to bring up GRUB menu. Select advanced options and then pick an older kernel to boot. If that doesnt work, please explain in more detail the external HDD recovery.