# 'Failed to connect to lvmetad' after changing Grub

Tags: boot, grub2

I have Ubuntu 18.02 installed on my Dell XPS laptop (single boot) with an encrypted disk.

But when I try to boot I get the error:
`Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to device scanning.`

Earlier today (when I still got into Ubuntu) I changed through '/etc/default/grub' the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` configuration, I added `resume=<swap_partition>` in an attempt to get hibernate working.
So I assume this change has something to do with the boot issue.

I tried through an ubuntu life usb to get to the grub file to change it back, but I cant find the right disk (see link to pictures below).

Any change is greatly appreciated, I need my computer for work tomorrow, and dont know what to do.

(I dont have enough reputation to post images, but you can find them here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/t5uom.jpg)

**Edit**

Questions:
1. Is it likely that the above change I made to the `/etc/default/grub` causes the `Failed to connect to lvmetad` problem? Are the two related?
2. How do I get into that grub configuration from the live usb?

Comment: That should be `/dev/sda1`!

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen thank you! I see it is mounted on `/cdrom`. I am not sure how from there to find the /etc/default/grub

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen /dev/sda1 is not encrypted so I think this cannot be the disk that I am looking for

Comment: See: https://askubuntu.com/questions/745218/ubuntu-wont-boot-because-of-lvmetad