# Find Grub configuration on different disk

Tags: boot, grub2, partitioning, mount

In my Ubuntu installation I changed something through
`sudoedit /etc/default/grub`
and now the installation won't boot anymore.

I am on a live usb with Ubuntu now, and it seems to me the other disk is /dev/sda1 and mounted on cdrom, but Im not sure how to get into the configurations that I changed.

When I type `sudoedit /etc/default/grub` I get into a file that doesnt have the changes I made (so I assume it is not the file I am looking for).

If I cd to `etc/default/` and then `nano grub.cfg` I get to a file that looks very different and doesn't have the same configurations.

How do I get to the grub configurations from the other disk?

(I have a single Ubuntu 18.04.03 install on a Dell XPS computer with an encrypted disk).

Some more information:

`lsblk` returns:

```
sda      8:0    1   7.5G  0 disk /cdrom
├─sda1   8:1    1     2G  0 part 
└─sda2   8:2    1   2.4M  0 part
```

and `cat proc/mounts/` returns amongst other:
`/dev/sda /cdrom iso9660 ro,noatime,nojoliet,check=s,map=n,blocksize=2048 0 0`

`sudo mount /dev/sda1 /media/sda1_test` returns:
`mount: /media/sda1_test: /dev/sda1 already mounted or mount point busy.`

if I cd to `media/sda1_test` and `ls` it seems empty

If I cd to `cdrom`, `ls` returns:
`EFI  README.diskdefines  boot  casper  dists  install  isolinux  md5sum.txt  pics  pool  preseed  ubuntu`

And I tried to find the grub file by
`sudo find / -name 'grub*'`
which returns amongst other:

```
/boot/grub
/usr/lib/grub
/rofs/usr/lib/grub
/rofs/var/lib/grub
```

I think the issue is that I am not in the right disk at all, since the disk is encrypted and I didn't get a prompt for a password.

and
`sudo find / -type d -wholename "etc/default"`
which returns:

```
find: ‘/proc/1593/task/1593/net’: Invalid argument
find: ‘/proc/1593/net’: Invalid argument
find: ‘/proc/8949/task/8949/net’: Invalid argument
find: ‘/proc/8949/net’: Invalid argument
find: ‘/run/user/999/gvfs’: Permission denied
```

Comment: /etc//default/grub on a 'live' system means on your current 'live' system and **not** your installed system. You need to `mount` your disk, then navigate to the folder you want and edit the file there. I usually mount to /mnt so I'd be editing /mnt/etc/default/grub but it'll depend on how/where you mount your hdd/ssd to.

Comment: Thank you! From what I can understand the disk is `/dev/sda1` and is mounted on `/cdrom`. However from there I am not sure how to get to /etc/default/grub. There is no etc folder and I cant seem to find the path (see pictures through the imgur link)

Comment: Are you sure you're talking about the correct device?  /dev/sdxy devices can include thumb-drives and you could be meaning the 'live' system. If you type `mount |grep sd` do you see your hdd?  (`lsblk` will list block devices where it should be detected).  Note because your drive is encrypted, you'll need to enter key to 'mount' it.  What OS are you using?  (it's easier on later OSes, and there was no 2018-February release!)

Comment: This has been asked before and I wrote a detailed answer, but the SE phone app is so poor on searching I can't find it.

Comment: @guiverc I guess I am not in the correct disk then, since I didnt get any prompt to enter a passphrase for description. I am not sure about disks at all, but from a different question I got that it might be /dev/sda1 (https://askubuntu.com/questions/1194562/failed-to-connect-to-lvmetad-after-changing-grub)

Comment: @guiverc when I enter `mount |grep sd` I get the following (https://imgur.com/a/Z6Q86tP). The disk that I try to get into is Ubuntu 18.02. The live USB also has Ubuntu 18.02

Comment: @OrganicMarble I searched through your answers but I couldnt find something related to grub configurations from a different disk...

Comment: Ubuntu releases are **year.month** and there was no Ubuntu release in February 2018.  Please don't provide pictures of text, they aren't easy to read.

Comment: @guiverc Yes, sorry, It is Ubuntu 18.04.03. And I added some text output instead of the pictures, hope that is better

Comment: This is the answer I was talking about, and I think is the procedure you need. https://askubuntu.com/a/891812/243321

Comment: Do recall what you changed? Why not just boot to Recovery Mode from the GRUB menu, correct the error in /etc/default/grub, update-grub, and reboot?